# Azure Devops yaml - How to escape a line break?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am testing out Azure Devops release pipelines to see if I could migrate our Octopus release pipelines to use it.

**Question 1**

One thing I'm struggling with is getting a multi-line variable to show in a Manual Validation task.

In the first job, I run a tool which performs some validations and produces an output consisting of several lines of text:

```
    - powershell: |
        # (removed some code here that performs validation and results 
        # in a multi-line string being in the $output variable)

        # Azure Devops doesn't support multi-line strings in variables, so convert it to a single line delimited with %0D
        $singleLineOutput = $output.replace("`r`n","%0D").replace("`n","%0D")
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PreviewResult;isOutput=true;]$singleLineOutput"
```

Then in the next job, I attempt to show this multi-line string as a Manual Verification step:

```
  - job: ManualApproval
    dependsOn: RunDnsPreview
    variables:
      previewResult: $[ replace(dependencies.RunDnsPreview.outputs['RunScript.PreviewResult'], '%0D', '\r\n') ]
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 1450 # job times out in 1 day
    steps:   
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          xxxx@xxxx.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the following: $(previewResult)'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

However, attempting to replace the %0D delimiter back to \r\n doesn't work, and the whole thing appears as a single massive line of text in the Manual Validation UI prompt.

How can we show a multi-line output in the Manual Validation step?

**Question 2: How to show the Instructions in the email?**

This is the email that you receive for the MAnual Validation. It doesn't seem to contain the instructions... how to include them?

[image: image of the email]

Comment: This manual validation step is very limited, I'd like to show a pre-formatted html structure in there and it just doesn't work, so, I hope I'm wrong, but, I don't think it's possible to send line-breaks through a variable and make it work with the 'Manual validation task', it seems there is an unescape operation running before the variable contents is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

This works for multiple lines..........

> instructions: | 
> 'Confirm you are deploying to the correct environment ' 
> 'You are about to deploy to ${{ variables.environment }}'

Comment: the question is about if the multi-line string is stored in a variable